# OutOfMemoryException using AFORGE.NET ProcessImage

Tags: c#, aforge

I have a large System.Drawing.Bitmap (14399 X 10799) that I am trying to process using AFORGE.NET.  My algorithm works very well with a smaller image but with this size of image I receive an OutOfMemoryException when I call Process().

Before calling Process(), my task manager reports that the application is using 613MB, at the time of the exception, it is using 609MB.

I have tried setting my platform target to x64 but this does not seem to affect the occurence of the exception.

I suspect that the exception is not related to the memory but something else, how can I circumvent it?

```
// lock image
        BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);

        // step 1 - turn background to black
        ColorFiltering colorFilter = new ColorFiltering();

        colorFilter.Red = new IntRange(0, 64);
        colorFilter.Green = new IntRange(0, 64);
        colorFilter.Blue = new IntRange(0, 64);
        colorFilter.FillOutsideRange = false;

        colorFilter.ApplyInPlace(bitmapData);

        // step 2 - locating objects
        BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();

        blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
        blobCounter.MinHeight = 5;
        blobCounter.MinWidth = 5;

        blobCounter.ProcessImage(bitmapData); //Crash
        Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
```

Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Comment: This is almost always related to the `Rectangle` being larger than the `Bitmap` area.  Check the dimensions of `bitmap` before you capture it into `bitmapData`.

Comment: _"I suspect that the exception is not related to the memory"_ - exceptions hardly ever lie. _"How can I circumvent it?"_ - by processing your image in chunks.

Comment: A 32-bit process doesn't raise OOM because it is completely out of memory, it goes kaboom when it cannot find a hole big enough to fit an allocation.  Your image needs a hole big enough to fit 622 megabytes, that's hard to come by.  A problem that's been trivially solved quite a while ago, 64-bit operating systems are universally available.  Change the platform target setting to AnyCPU to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

The memory usage could be quite high if your image contains a lot of blobs. Have you tried with a blank image of the same size ?

If it is really caused by your image having too many blobs, you could try to add more constraints on your blob filtering.

Answer (score 0):

i had simillar issue, 
just use the ResizeBilinear filter or any other resize filter in Aforge.Imaging.Filters (you don't need the full quality image if you are processing it just to get some information)and any modification you want to make for the source image it's done by scaling back the points for objects you found and below is a simple method to get a temporary scaled down image for processing

```
 Bitmap ResizeMyImage(Bitmap Source, int scalefactor)
        {
            int newHeight = Source.Height / scalefactor;
            int newWidth = (int)(Source.Width * (newHeight / (float)Source.Height));
            ResizeBilinear filter = new ResizeBilinear(newWidth, newHeight);
            return filter.Apply(Source);
        }
```